# Non-repeating PRNG algorithm

Tags: random, mapping

The following algorithm generates an array of non-repeating random numbers (the example is written in Fortran 95):

```fortran
program test
implicit none

real :: x
integer :: i, aux
integer, dimension(100) :: y = 0

do i=2,100
  call RANDOM_NUMBER(x)
  aux = int(3 * x) + 1 ! random number: 1, 2 or 3
  aux = aux + y(i-1) ! adding previous selected number
  y(i) = MOD(aux,4) ! mod 4 gives the final result: 0, 1, 2 or 3
  print*, y(i)
enddo

end program test
```

On another discussion forum, a member proposed this algorithm as a solution to a challenge of how to output non-repeating numbers using a regular random number generator and a fixed amount of operations per loop (so for instance cycling when a random value is the same as the previous would not give a constant number of operations per loop).

His algorithm seems to work well, the results are uniformly distributed and there are no obvious patterns in any sub-strings of any in the output (I searched for sub-strings of sizes 2 to 5 and all behaved as expected). But what puzzles me in this solution is that the random number generator is outputting only three possible numbers (0, 1 or 2) and yet the whole algorithm outputs four possible results (0, 1, 2 or 3). How is this possible? I thought that mapping down the results of a PRNG could be done, but not mapping it up (e.g. if a PRNG produces numbers between 0 and 7, they can be mapped as 0-3 => 0 and 4-7 =>1, but a PRNG producing only 0's and 1's cannot produce results between 0-7 *in a same loop* – since one could obviously group three results in order to map 000 => 0, 001 => 1, ... 111 => 7).

---

Edit: this is the same algorithm but written in pseudocode, as this question is not related to Fortran nor any programming language in particular

```
x ← 0
do
  aux ← random number between 1 and 3
  aux ← aux + x
  x ← aux MOD 4
  print x
enddo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first sight, the algorithm above seems to take as input random integers ranging between `0` and `2` (i.e. 3 values) and output random integers ranging between `0` and `3` (i.e. 4 values) for each cycle, which seems to be problematic due to upsampling. But actually the algorithm is always choosing among 3 options only, given that each value cannot be the same as the previous one. For instance, if the very first random integer selected is `0`, there are three possible values for the next integer (`1`, `2` or `3`), which is exactly what the range PRGN is providing. So the key is to realize that 3 random values are being mapped into 4 *non-repeating* random values, and this can be done without causing any unwanted patterns.

Therefore, there is no problem using `MOD N+1` for a random input ranging from `0` to `N`, because the amount of information does not change with that. But when we use `MOD N+2` or larger, we actually do observe patterns that shouldn't be there if the output was truly random. For instance, certain sequences of two consecutive numbers never appear: e.g. taking `N = 3` (i.e. input between `0` and `2`) and `MOD 5`, one will never see a `0` followed by a `4`, since there is no input such that the expression `((input + 1) + 0) MOD 5 = 4` would be true.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I may be missing something, because I don't remember Fortran perfectly.

Why are you allowed to access y(i-1) when i = 1. Isn't that an array boundary violation? I will assume that it just returns zero or something.

The first time through the loop, aux will end up being 1, 2 or 3, assuming y(i-1) = 0, and y(1) will be the same (1, 2 or 3). Then the second time through, aux will be (1, 2 or 3) + (1, 2 or 3) which will be 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 and y(2) will be 0, 1, 2 or 3, since 4 MOD 4 = 0 and 5 MOD 4 = 1. From there on out, y(n) can be 0, 1, 2, or 3, since you will always be adding (1, 2 or 3) to (0, 1, 2 or 3) and modding by 4.

I have the feeling you are making an assumption that I am not making, and I don't see what valid assumption would restrict the output to only 3 values.

The RANDOM_NUMBER function assigns `0 <= x < 1`. It's not clear to me why you are thinking about binary representation of the numbers, since you don't seem to be using bitwise operators.

**Edit:**
That makes more sense. I didn't understand that your main focus was on the distribution of the numbers, statistically speaking. I could probably explain my thoughts on the subject better with a number series, or some statistical notation, if I remembered much about either from academia, but like my wrestler roommate in college who did anything to avoid algebra would have done, I will just map out my thoughts with a bunch of empirical numbers:

**The first time through the loop**, you would end up with the following possible values: (trivial case)

aux: could be 1, 2 or 3

y(i-1): 0

aux + y(i-1): 1, 2 or 3

y(i): 1, 2 or 3

Now **the second time through**, you actually have to deal with the weightings caused by the probability of getting each possible result:

aux: 1, 2 or 3

y(i-1): 1, 2 or 3

aux + y(i-1): {the sum of each combination of aux and y(i-1)} 1 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 {meaning there is a 1/10 chance of getting a 1, same for 2, same for 6 and a 1/5 chance of getting a 3, same for a 5, and a 3/10 chance of getting a 4; this is not a very even distribution}

y(i) = 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 {same rationale, a little more even distribution for this "output"}

**The third time through**:

aux: 1, 2 or 3

y(i-1): 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3

aux + y(i-1): {after sorting} 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6

y(i): {after sorting} 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3

Balancing a) the risk of assuming that this equalizing trend will continue for the distribution of values with b) the desire to avoid the growing complexity of calculating these sample values, it seems reasonable to extrapolate that the distribution will be somewhat even for growing i.

The best way to prove it to yourself for sure is to alter the algorithm to keep arrays of possible results for each iteration, and output probabilities, rather than random numbers. I will leave that as an exercise for you.

I suspect that the error caused by not having the range of possible values of `aux - y(i-1)` be a multiple of the right hand operand of MOD, is offset by the hashing nature of MOD. What I mean is, I think that the lopsidedness of probability is distributed within the range of possible values in a sliding, or more likely a rotating, window, throughout the range of values of y(i), from one iteration to the next. Hopefully you understand what I mean by that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So a couple of things: first, my compiler handles y(0) as `0`, but I updated my code to avoid any problems with other compilers (that's bad practise from my side, I know). Secondly, I am using the RANDOM_NUMBER because Fortran does not have a native random integer function, but surely the two first lines inside the loop are equivalent to a random integer function. Thirdly, I do understand that MOD 4 outputs results ranging from 0 to 3, and that the input reaching this function does allow it output this full range, but my question is something else:

Comment: if we have an input of 3 random integers, how can this algorithm output 4 random integers for each cycle? I would expect to see patterns in the output. As I explained in my question, I believe this is related to the idea of mapping. Let's think a more extreme example to illustrate what I find hard to grasp: if you have a PRGN outputting only 0's and 1's, can you map each single result (using addition and mod) into a range of 0-99 random numbers displaying no unwanted patterns? I don't think so. And if that's correct, then how can you map 3 random integers into 4 random integers?

Comment: Regarding your alternate algorithm, I suggest that you could make the deviation from randomness become negligible well before reaching 100 samples by doing something like adding a binary value like 01100 (the exact value is for visualization only) which does a rotate right each iteration, to a binary value like 10110 which toggles bits each iteration, to a binary value like 11001 which does a rotate left each iteration. Then you could add feedback, like the y(i-1) and maybe a y(i-5), possibly with coefficients, and then MOD. I think pseudo-symmetry and complexity should even the distribution.

Comment: And you would probably want a seed value, based on the time or the temperature in Kelvin times the number of shares of Oracle stock changing hands YTD, at least initially, and maybe sprinkled into the algorithm too. I may not have made it clear that your random 0 or 1 value would be included for each iteration. Am I going overboard with this fictitious algorithm, and all you wanted was an up or down vote on a less complicated algorithm?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, I really appreciate it, but I suspect we are still misunderstanding each other. You wrote about some error, and yet I never mentioned any error at all: the algorithm I posted does seem to work well, and my question is rather related to why does it work. In the comments you also proposed some improvements to the algorithm (how to seed it, how to diminish the deviation from randomness) but this also is not the point. I am also not looking for a simple "up or down vote" on the algorithm I posted, I am simply asking what is the basis for this algorithm to work.

Comment: I had given the example that if we have a random integer generator outputting either 0's and 1's, it would be quite impossible to map this result using only the sum and modulo operators into a range of let's say 0-99. If this is correct, then I wonder why mapping values ranging between 0 and 2 into values ranging between 0 and 3 does work. If what I wrote before is not correct, then I am curious how would that work, how can one generate more "information" per cycle than it was originally there. Does this make sense?

Comment: I am thinking that this question might actually be more suitable for the Maths SE, since I am interested in the theoretical side of these calculations rather than anything to do with implementation or programming itself.

Comment: "Error" was a poor choice of words, as it means something completely different in computer science and statistics. I simply meant "deviation from statistical randomness", meaning the "statistical error" or "disturbance." I think that I understand you. I stand by the relevance of my answer. Is it not correct that you are concerned with the inherent inaccuracy of upsampling as opposed to downsampling, since you are trying to insert precision where it is lacking, rather than removing precision? I believe that hashing with MOD obviates that concern.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up, I understand what you meant now. As for hashing with MOD, I think that is only true if the input numbers are larger than the MOD argument. Nevertheless, I believe I found the answer for my question: there is no problem using MOD N+1 for a random input of N, because the amount of information does not change with that. See, the random input in my case has 3 possible values, and though the output does have 4 possible values each individual result cannot be the previous one, totalling still 3 possible results! So when I do MOD N+2 or larger, I actually do observe ...

Comment: ... random patterns that shouldn't be there (for instance, certain sequences of two consecutive numbers never appear). For instance, if N=3 (i.e. input 0-2) and we take MOD 5, once will never see a 0 followed by a 4, since the no (input + 0) MOD 5 = 4.

Comment: I gave you an upvote for your answer and effort, which I really appreciate and led to the correct answer, but if you don't mind I believe I will add my own answer to this question.

Comment: You're welcome. I learned some things. Do what you think is appropriate for stackoverflow.